# Quotient ring of a matrix ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

> Let $F$ be a field. Consider the set
>   $$R =  \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
> a & b \\
> 0 & c
> \end{bmatrix} : a, b, c \in F \right\}$$
>   Think of a non-trivial two-sided ideal of $R$ and describe in a concrete way the quotient ring $R/I$. (Your description should be explicit enough to make the fact that $R/I$ is a commutative ring completely transparent.)

I can think of some ideals of $R$, however I don't understand the meaning of a quotient ring when it comes to matrices nor how to describe them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of a ring is no different when the elements of the ring are matrices (or vectors, or elephants, or ...).

Given a ring $R$ and an ideal $I \trianglelefteq R$ the quotient $R/I$ is given by
$$R/I = \{  x + I : x \in R \}$$
with addition and multiplication defined by $(x+I)+(y+I) = (x+y)+I$ and $(x+I) \cdot (y+I) = (x \cdot y) + I$.

Here it's exactly the same. If $I \trianglelefteq R$ is an ideal then
$$R/I = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix} + I : a,b,c \in F \right \}$$
To make it really explicit, notice that
$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix} + I = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a + x & b + y \\ 0 & c + z \end{bmatrix} : \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ 0 & z \end{bmatrix} \in I \right\}$$

Comment: Would any chosen ideal make the quotient ring R/I a commutative ring? I have tested many ideals and upon switching sides when multiplying, I never get equal matrices, which would imply that the quotient ring isn't commutative. Any advice?

Comment: +1 to Clive, and a hint to OP: if $r_1$ and $r_2$ are generic elements of $R$, and $I$ is an ideal such that $R/I$ is commutative, then $r_1r_2-r_2r_1\in I$ for all $r_1,r_2\in R$. This is because we should have $(r_1+I)(r_2+I)=(r_2+I)(r_1+I)$ by commutativity of the quotient ring. So calculate $r_1r_2-r_2r_1$ for those generic matrices, and see what you get.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have found the only commutative quotient ring to be the quotient by the ideal of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}0 & c\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ for $c$ in our field. Is this correct?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen i.e $I=[R,R]$

Comment: @Exterior: That's correct. Well done.